Can we interchange the pullback and exterior derivative for a $C^1$ map?
In a recent lecture, the following statement was discussed:
Suppose $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open subset and $\varphi \in \Omega^k(U)$ a $C^1$ k-form, further suppose $V \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is open and $F:V \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a $C^2$ function and $F(V) \subset U$. Then it holds that $d(F^*\varphi) = F^*(d\varphi)$.
This statement makes sense to me because $F^*\varphi$ is still a $C^1$ form, allowing us to apply the exterior derivative.
However, in a different proof, we used a $C^1$ map $\tilde u: W \to \mathbb{R}^n$, with $W\subset \mathbb{R}^k$ open and wrote $\tilde u^*d\varphi = d \tilde u^*\varphi$. In my opinion, you cannot change the Pullback and exterior derivative, since $\tilde u^*\varphi$ would only be guaranteed to be continuous thus $d\tilde u^*\varphi$ might not exist. Am I missing something here, or is this a valid concern?
The beginning of the proof of Stokes theorem(added after kobe's comment):
Statement: Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an oriented k dimensional $C^1$ manifold with boundary $\partial M$ and let $W \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $M$ contained in $W$. Then for a $k-1$ form $\varphi \in \Omega^k-1(W)$ continuously differentiable and with compact support on $M$ with the induced orientation on $\partial M$ from $M$ satisfies $\int_M d\varphi = \int_{\partial M} \varphi$.
Beginning of the proof:
Wlog we can assume that there is a positively oriented Parameterization $ u: U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ of $M$, such that $K := supp(\varphi) \cup M \subset u(U)$. From here we can find an $C^1$ extension $\tilde u :W \to \mathbb{R}^n$ of $u$. Meaning, that $u$ and $\tilde u$ coincide on $u^{-1}(K)$. From this it follows:
$\int_K d(\varphi) = \int_{u^{-1}(K)} \tilde u ^*d\varphi = \int_{u^{-1}(K)} d\tilde u ^*\varphi$.
Any clarification would be appreciated.

I cannot comment on the full proof since it has not been provided, but the equation $u^d\varphi = du^\varphi$ holds true in the weak sense (or in the sense of currents), but not pointwise for the reason you mentioned.

@kobe I have added the relevant part of the proof

It's always worth writing this out in coordinates. Roughly, the calculation goes like this:
\begin{align*}
\int_K d\phi &= \int d(a_Idy^I)\\
&= \int_K\partial_ka_I dy^k\wedge dy^I\\
&= \int_{u^{-1}(K)}\partial_ka_I \partial_jy^k\partial_Jy^I\,dx^j\wedge dx^J\\
&= -\int_{u^{-1}(K)}a_I\partial_k(\partial_jy^k\partial_Jy^I)\,dx^j\wedge dx^J
\end{align*}
Your question is about the last line. Since $\partial y$ is known only to be continuous, $\partial_jy^k\partial_Jy^I$ is not differentiable. However, it is weakly differentiable. The last line then follows by the definition of a weak derivative.
If your professor has not discussed weak derivatives, then you should ask them your question (without necessarily mentioning weak derivatives).

Thanks for your answer. We have never discussed weak derivatives in class. Would you be so kind and provide a good reference for the basic definition of a weak derivative.

By the way, I'm assuming that the boundary of $K$ is smooth. You can try taking a look at the wikipedia article on a weak derivative. But I suspect your professor isn't expecting you to know this.
